# Get N(3) lists (based on ENUM gender (male, female, other)) from java 8 stream and filter conditions based on ENUM

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

how can I create N lists based on gender Enum types? If I have 3 possible GENDER enums (male, female, other), i need 3 Lists . How do I achieve this using java 8 streams API?

I need something like a MAP with 3 keys in this case. genderMap.get(GENDER.male).

```
Map<GENDER, List<Person>> genderMap;
```

tried with partitioningBy

```
Map<Boolean, List<Person>> genderMap= people.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(malePredicate()));

System.out.println("MALE "+genderMap.get(true));
System.out.println("FEMALE "+genderMap.get(false));

private static Predicate<Person> malePredicate(){
    return p ->  p.getGender() != null && p.getGender().equalsIgnoreCase("male");
}

private static Predicate<Person> femalePredicate(){
    return p ->  p.getGender() != null && p.getGender().equalsIgnoreCase("female");
}
```

- **MALE** [Person [id=1, name=SAMPLE_1, age=11, gender=male, sal=100,
  monthlyExpenseAmount=120.00], Person [id=2, name=SAMPLE_2, age=12,
  gender=male, sal=100, monthlyExpenseAmount=120.00]]
- **FEMALE** [Person [id=0, name=SAMPLE_0, age=10, gender=other, sal=100,
  monthlyExpenseAmount=120.00], Person [id=3, name=SAMPLE_3, age=13,
  gender=female, sal=100, monthlyExpenseAmount=100.00], Person [id=4,
  name=SAMPLE_4, age=14, gender=female, sal=100,
  monthlyExpenseAmount=100.00], Person [id=5, name=SAMPLE_5, age=15,
  gender=female, sal=100, monthlyExpenseAmount=100.00]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupingBy()` and `toList()`:

```
Map<Gender, List<Person>> genderMap = people.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getGender, Collectors.toList()));
```

See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/HZYWiy) for demo.

Comment: Or use the overload of `groupingBy(java.util.function.Function)` which defaults to defaults to using `toList` downstream.

Answer (score 0):

`.partitioningBy()` is used to partition the results into 2 groups.

You are looking for [`.groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function))

```
Map<Gender, List<Person>> genderMap = people.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getGender));
```